# Magento2: In which table Resource Access dropdown (tree-resources-container) is saved?

Tags: magento2, user-roles, acl, admin-user, resources

```
public function getRules()
{
    $resoId = 'Mageants_AdvancedPermissions::catalog_attributes';
    $permission = 'allow';
    $rid = $this->_adminSession->getUser()->getRole()->getData('role_id');
    $resources = $this->_rulesCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection = $resources->addFieldToFilter('role_id', array('eq' => $rid))->addFieldToFilter('resource_id', array('eq' => $resoId))->addFieldToFilter('permission', array('eq' => $permission));
    return $collection;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All the roles save in

> **authorization_role** table

and depending on role id rules will be set in

> **authorization_rule** table

Comment: upload image in question @user80581

Comment: it's your local path it not access by globally @user80581

Comment: https://prnt.sc/nypcna

Comment: Yes this stores in authorization_role  and authorization_rule tables which magento2's default tables @user80581